# my FullCalendar is not working due to an error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have an issue, my javascript code is not executing when it calls the fullCalendar library. The fullCalendar library version is 5.10.1, and my jquery version is 3.6.0. My calendar is not shown as is.

Please help me or someone can guide me on what am I doing wrong?.
Thank you for your help.

> ERROR: jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Here is my jquery/javascript script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element
        .find(".fc-content")
        .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
      element.find(".closeon").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
      });
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent) {
      var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
      calEvent.title = title;
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Kindly add the HTML for `#calendar`

Comment: it just `<div id='calendar'></div>`

Comment: Please do not change the original question to any of the provided answers. You can instead add what you're trying to a fiddle and share the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FullCalendar` 5.10.1 is not a jQuery plugin hence it cannot not be initialize like `$("#calendar").fullCalendar(...)`. You should instead initialize it like so

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'),  {
        // header: {
        //     left: "prev,next today",
        //     center: "title",
        //     right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
        // },
        // defaultView: "month",
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        // selectHelper: false,
        editable: true,
        // eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

        select: function(info ) {
            let title = prompt("Event Content:");
            if (title) {
                calendar.addEvent({
                    title: title,
                    start: info.startStr,
                    end: info.endStr
                })
            }
            calendar.unselect();
        },

        eventDidMount: function(info) {
            // code for when event is rendered
        },

        eventClick: function(info) {
            var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", info.event.title);
            
            // code to update event.
        }

    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: update my code... and still not working... see code above

Comment: What you tried is invalid. You placed `calendar.render();` at a wrong place.

Comment: got it ./. thanks for the help

Comment: @Aman you mean everything is working now?

Comment: yes, everything is working now.. fixed the place of the rendering part

Comment: however, when I double click on the calendar and then when I try it again it wont work...

Comment: That 's because the options are different in fullcalender 5. I will add the full code soon.

Comment: ok thank you.. is your full code going to be the one when they add something in input field it will show on calendar as well?

Comment: @Aman I've updated my answer. I couldn't do all because Fullcalender's documentation is terrible. Kindly check it out.

Comment: Exactly. Or you can store it in a database. But localstorage is easier to implement.

Comment: let me do that and  if i got stuck.. I will post it here